# How to plot a 3-D function using Julia's Plots package?

Tags: plot, julia, gnuplot

Is it possible to reproduce this graph using the Julia Plots Package?
[Plotting using gnuplot](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-gaston-v1-0-0-plotting-using-gnuplot/40958/3?u=heradri)

```
x = y = -15:0.4:15
f1 = (x,y) -> @. sin(sqrt(x*x+y*y))/sqrt(x*x+y*y)
surf(x, y, f1, w = :p, marker = "dot", Axes(hidden3d = :on))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly the same, but you can plot a surface with `surface`:

```
using Plots
x = y = -15:0.4:15
f(x,y) = sin(sqrt(x^2+y^2))/sqrt(x^2+y^2)
surface(x, y, f)
```

which will give

[image: surface plot]

or a `wireframe`

```
wireframe(x, y, f)
```

will give

[image: wireframe plot]

But if you really want a 3D scatter, then you need to create the mesh by hand and rearrange the data into vectors I think, like

```
X = [x for x in x for y in y]
Y = [y for x in x for y in y]
scatter3d(X, Y, f.(X,Y))
```

[image: scatter3d plot]